# Convert fontawesome unicode F015 to readable unicode like &#xF015 ;

Tags: javascript, unicode, font-awesome

I'm having a global variable that gives fontawesome unicode : **var = "f015"**

What i'd like, is  to set this icon inside a vuetify v-icon.

So far, I've seen that v-icon can read & #xf015; (without space) and display it as fontawesome icon.

I guess that what I need to return is  but concatened with my var, making something like  '&#x' + var + ';' with no string.

But the problem is that I can't return anything else then a string to the template html and I need to put that variable as icon :

```
 <v-icon style="font-family: FontAwesome;font-style: normal; position:absolute; left:6px; top:8px;"color="white"size="18">
'&#x' + var + ';'
</v-icon>
```

I can't put `&#x + f015 + ;` without string

there is what I tried so far, and is also not working

```
{{ String.fromCharCode(parseInt(var)) }}
{{ String.fromCharCode(parseInt('&#x' + var + ';')) }}
{{ String.fromCharCode(parseInt(\u + var)) }}

{{'&#x' + var + ';'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem sovled with this :  {{ String.fromCharCode(parseInt(variable, 16)) }} where variable is "F015"